# How to create a Carousel with text on side (Not Full-Size) - Pictured

Tags: css, carousel, rows

I'm trying to create a carousel similar to the picture...

Text on the side which alternates sides on each slide - if that makes sense?

I'm currently trying to use a Row and Two Col's in Boostrap but a bit puzzled.

Sorry for being a newb!

Thanks in advance for any help - any pointers or suggestions and I'll try and watch a video on making it happen. Just a bit unsure what is the best route?

--

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBbvt.png)

This is my current code:

```
        <section id="work">
 <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="images/WA.JPG" class="d-block w-88" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="images/TIC.JPG" class="d-block w-88" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="Images/yuriy-kovalev-RGK5GDJ907U-unsplash.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"  data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"  data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div> 
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}

.sildetext-area h5 {
    font-size: 21px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.text {
    display: none;
}
.sildetext-area {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBbvt.png" style="width:50%">
  

<div class="sildetext-area">

             <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
</div>

</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBbvt.png" style="width:50%">
  <div class="sildetext-area">

   <h5>Second slide label</h5>
<p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBbvt.png" style="width:50%">
  <div class="sildetext-area">

   <h5>Third slide label</h5>
<p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

Please see the snippet here I create a slider with your image.